# Importing data directly into excel sheet, from data accessed through Material Project opensource API's

Tags: data-analysis, excel, information-extraction, api

I had a general doubt. If I want to extract some data, say the information regarding a particular chemical using API of material projects(a site that has open-source info on, say elements) available on the internet, and compile the information on an excel sheet, what would be the simplest way to do so? Can someone guide..it would be great, thanks!

Comment: I think Excel has the option to directly import data from the web. Under the `Data` ribbon, you should be able to see `Get Data > From Other Sources > From Web`. There you can directly input the API url and even further transform the data if necessary.

Comment: Thank You, got it!